# Starting method in all implemented classes

Tags: java, interface

I'm kind of new to Java and have a rather simple question:

I have an interface, with a method:

```
public interface Interface_Updatable {

    public void updateViewModel();

}
```

I implement this interface in several classes. Each class then of course has that method `updateViewModel`.

Edit: I instantiate these classes in a main function. Here I need code that calls `updateViewModel` for all objects that implement the interface.

Is there an easy way to do it combined? I don't want to call every method from every object instance separately and keep that updated. Keeping it updated might lead to errors in the long run.

Comment: Starts it when? Where? How does it know the instances?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I suspect what you're asking is exactly what's unclear to OP ;-)

Comment: You need to construct instances from the classes who implements the interface , without instances you cant call the methods

Comment: Well I´m using AndroidStudio right now. The main class instanciates the other classes. In the main class, at some point, I want all instances to use the update method... but I dont want to call out every update method of every object seperately, since I have many classes.

Answer (score 0):

The short form is: **no**, there's no simple way to "call this method on all instances of classes that implement this interface".

At least not in a way that's sane and maintainable.

So what should you do instead?

In reality you almost never want to just "call it on all instances", but you have *some kind of relation* between the thing that should trigger the update and the instances for which it should be triggered.

For example, the naming of the method suggests that instances of `Interface_Updatable` are related to the view model. So if they "care" about changes to the view model, they could register themselves as interested parties by doing something like `theViewModel.registerForUpdates(this)`, the view model could hold on to a list of all objects that registered like this and then loop over all the instances and calls `updateViewModel` on each one (of course one would need to make sure that unregistration also happens, where appropriate).

This is the classical listener pattern at work.

But the high-level answer is: you almost never want to call something on "all instances", instead the instances you want to call it on have *some relation* to each other and you would need to make that relation *explicit* (via some registration mechanism like the one described above).

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to call this method on all classes that implement this interface. The problem is that you need to somehow keep track of all the classes that implement this interface.

A possible object-oriented way to do this would be passing a list containing objects that are instances of classes that implement the `Interface_Updateable` interface to a function, and then calling `updateViewModel` on each object in that list:

```
public void updateViewModels(List<Interface_Updateable> instances) {
    for(var instance : instances) {
        instance.updateViewModel();
    }
}
```